# Reference property in Gradle Properties

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My **gradle.properties.kts** files has the following contents:

```
build_version=develop
build_version_code=2
include_vas=false
```

In my **build.gradle.kts** looks as follows:

```
plugins {
    id(Plugins.androidApplication)
    kotlin(Plugins.kotlinAndroid)
    kotlin(Plugins.kotlinExtensions)
    kotlin(Plugins.kapt)
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion(Configs.compileVersion)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = Configs.applicationId
        minSdkVersion(Configs.minSdkVersion)
        targetSdkVersion(Configs.targetSdkVersion)
        testInstrumentationRunner = Configs.testInstrumentationRunner
        versionCode =
    }


  buildTypes{

  }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar", "*.arr"))))
        implementation(Libs.stdLib)
        implementation(Libs.sunmiui)
        implementation(Libs.slf4j)
        implementation(Libs.appCompact)
        implementation(Libs.otpView)
        implementation(Libs.vectordrawableAnimated)
        implementation(Libs.materialComponents)
        implementation(Libs.recyclerView)
        implementation(Libs.constraintLayout)
        implementation(Libs.junit)
        implementation(Libs.testRunner)
        implementation(Libs.expressoCore)
        implementation(Libs.lifecyleExtensions)
        implementation(Libs.lifecyleCompiler)
        implementation(Libs.roomRuntime)
        implementation(Libs.databindingCompiler)
        implementation(Libs.rxjava)
        implementation(Libs.rxjavaAndroid)
        implementation(Libs.glide)
        implementation(Libs.glideCompiler)
        implementation(Libs.gson)
        implementation(Libs.joda)
        implementation(Libs.countrycodePicker)
        implementation(Libs.timber)
        implementation(Libs.daggerandroidSupport)
        implementation(Libs.daggerandroidProcessor)
    }
```

I am in the process of converting my current gradle scripts to kotlin DSL. The current challenge I am facing is that in the defaultConfig:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(Configs.compileVersion)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = Configs.applicationId
        minSdkVersion(Configs.minSdkVersion)
        targetSdkVersion(Configs.targetSdkVersion)
        testInstrumentationRunner = Configs.testInstrumentationRunner
        versionCode =
    }
```

I refer to the versionCode that is defined in the gradle.properties. The code below was how it was done before the conversion.

```
defaultConfig
        {

            multiDexEnabled true
            applicationId "jfjfjrjrjr.comn.jejeu"
            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode build_version_code as Integer
            versionName build_version
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
```

How can I do this in Kotlin

Comment: Why don't you take it to **ext** rather than **gradle.properties.kts** file

Comment: This is because its a property that is used when building the apk on azure's build pipelines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing as suggested by @Jeel Vankhede is the following:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled = true
    applicationId = Configs.applicationId
    minSdkVersion(Configs.minSdkVersion)
    targetSdkVersion(Configs.targetSdkVersion)
    var value = Integer.parseInt(project.property("build_version_code") as String?)
    versionCode = value
    versionName = project.property("build_version") as String?
    testInstrumentationRunner = Configs.testInstrumentationRunner
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Since [v0.16.3](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/releases/tag/v0.16.3) of the Gradle Kotlin DSL (included in Gradle v4.7) one could use property delegates for the values declared in `gradle.properties` like follows:

```
val yourVariable: TypeOfYourVariable by project
```

Your example would look like:

```
val build_version_code: String by project

defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode = build_version_code    
    ...
}
```

Comment: ugh, this is pretty lame, things were easier when you could just do `findProperty("build_version_code")`

Comment: property delegates example: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

Answer (score 8):

There's no clean way about obtaining it, but you can use **[Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html)** interface and use it's [property()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#property-java.lang.String-) method to obtain your **gradle.properties.kts** variables from it like below code:

```
project.property('your_variable_name_here')
```

For your instance:

```
versionCode project.property('build_version_code')
```

This is how you can set all your variables from your property file.

Comment: I get the following error message when I use the method above:java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Comment: I just forgot to mention that it will return Object type though you'll need to cast it.. use like this if variable is Integer : `versionCode project.property('build_version_code') as Integer`

Comment: I had cast it and still I get the same error:                                                   versionCode = project.property("build_version_code") as Int?
versionName = project.property("build_version") as String?

Comment: Is that still a casting exception or any new error?

Comment: Still produces the same error as previously stated: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer Possible causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Answer (score 3):

You can access a Project variable, e.g port, with:

```
val port: String by project
```

The above will fail if port is not set. If unsure, use

```
val port: String? by project
```

Then you could do:

```
 if (port != null) {...}
```